# Qt subclassed QStyledItemDelegate paint method is never called

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, model-view

**Update: my paint method was not const**

I have a custom `QTableView` connected to a `QAbstractTableModel`.

I recently created a `QStyledItemDelegate` subclass and its `paint` method prints a debugging message and then it calls the parent paint and then it prints another debugging message.

I have called `view->setItemDelegate` and I have checked that the item delegate in my view is the one I gave it (just to be sure).

However, my program just renders things the same way it did before and never prints the debug message in `paint`.  It does print a debug message in the delegate's constructor, so I know it should be printing if that function ever gets called.

Here is a stripped down version of my code, let me know one of these:

1. **Can you see what is wrong?**
2. **How I can debug Qt classes like this?**
3. **What other relevant code I should post to diagnose this problem?**
4. **Is there some common solution I could try?**

Thanks!

Here is the entire delegate .h and .cpp files (minus includes/namespace)

```
class QtCellItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    QtCellItemDelegate( QWidget *parent = NULL );

    void paint( QPainter *painter,
                const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                const QModelIndex &index );

    QSize sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                    const QModelIndex & index ) const;

    virtual ~QtCellItemDelegate();
};

QtCellItemDelegate::QtCellItemDelegate( QWidget *parent ) :
    QStyledItemDelegate( parent )
{
    qDebug() << "CONSTRUCT";
}

void QtCellItemDelegate::paint( QPainter *painter,
                                const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                const QModelIndex &index )
{
    painter->save();
    qDebug() << "Begin Paint";
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );

    qDebug() << "   Begin custom paint";
    // omitted...

    qDebug() << "End paint";
    painter->restore();
}

QSize QtCellItemDelegate::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                     const QModelIndex & index ) const 
{
    return QSize( 60, 60 );
}

QtCellItemDelegate::~QtCellItemDelegate()
{
    qDebug() << "Destroy delegate!";
}
```

So the debugging output tells me the constructor is called (but not the destructor...) and that I am actaully setting the same deleagate to the view as I think I am.  However, the messages in `paint` never get printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are not declaring your subclass's paint method as const.  As such, it's not overriding the superclass method (const and non-const methods are considered to have different signatures from each other) and that's why your paint method doesn't get called.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out like an hour ago...too bad this project is due in the morning. At least I almost got it work in time.  Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @Matt: if you work with Visual Studio or a C++11 compatible compiler you can use the `override` keyowrd, to make sure you correctly override virtual methods. If you compile with Visual Studio and additionally on Linux/Mac, just use a macro.